# click() function not working for onclick="try {if (isReadyToContinue()) {setBusyIndicator();} else {return false;}} catch (e) {;};"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I need to click on a link in my application and this is what I see in inspect element

```
<a href="/devint-webimpact/obtainSummary.do?org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=ab581e51b9a087012a53c22d92b390cb&amp;level=3&amp;index=1" title="219 - Trial Description" onclick="try {if (isReadyToContinue()) {setBusyIndicator();} else {return false;}} catch (e) {;};">219 - Trial Description</a>
```

This is the code I've tried but is not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("219 - Trial Description")).click();
```

Can someone please help what can I use instead to click on the link.

Comment: Step 1) don't swallow exceptions `catch (e) {;}`

Comment: @DivyaVJMohan What error do you see?